# Site Search/Point Location in Voronoi Diagram

Tags: computational-geometry, voronoi

Given Voronoi diagram, how to locate which polygon contains query point q? What if q is one of the Voronoi sites, would it make any difference?

Do we walk through each polygon and check point-in-polygon? It is too expensive and slow to do that.

Comment: So if I have a Voronoi diagram with over 1 million cells I have to have some sort of spatial index on top of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a well-studied topic. Search for "point location within a convex subdivision." Here is one paper that can lead you to others:

> Cheng, Siu-Wing, and Man-Kit Lau. "Adaptive point location in planar convex subdivisions." *International Symposium on Algorithms and Computation*. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg, 2015. ([Journal link](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-48971-0_2).)

Or maybe this presentation is easier to penetrate:

> Subhash Suri, "Point Location." ([PDF download](https://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~suri/cs235/Location.pdf).)

Comment: Some conflict of interest: Subhash was my Ph.D. student.